# Notify when all thread loops ended their iteration in main thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, loops, deadlock, condition-variable

I've the following code:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <syncstream>

int main() {
  std::condition_variable myCV;
  std::mutex myMutex;
  bool isRunning{ true };

  const size_t numberOfThreads{ 6 };

  std::vector<std::jthread> threads;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    threads.emplace_back(
      [&isRunning, &myMutex, &myCV, i]() {
        std::unique_lock loopLock(myMutex);
        while (isRunning) {
          myCV.wait(loopLock);
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        }
        std::osyncstream oss{ std::cout };
        oss << "Ended thread " << i << std::endl;
      }
    );
  }


  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myCV.notify_all();
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    std::cout << "Test loop " << i << std::endl;
  }

  isRunning = false;
  myCV.notify_all();

  return 0;
}
```

The code instantiates some thread. Every thread has an internal infinite loop and the iteration starts when they're notified by the `myCV` condition variable.

The idea is to start the iteration, wait that all threads make their work, collect results (not shown here) and then start the next execution iteration.

My problem is that the main thread doesn't wait the end of all thread loop iterations before going ahead, and I don't know how to do it.

I've think about a solution like this one:

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <syncstream>
#include <atomic>

int main() {
  std::condition_variable myCV;
  std::mutex myMutex;
  bool isRunning{ true };

  std::condition_variable loopEndCV;
  std::atomic<size_t> threadCounter{ 0 };
  std::mutex loopEndMutex;

  const size_t numberOfThreads{ 6 };

  std::vector<std::jthread> threads;

  std::cout << "Instantiating threads..." << std::endl;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < numberOfThreads; i++) {
    threads.emplace_back(
      [&, i]() {
        std::unique_lock loopLock(myMutex);
        while (isRunning) {
          myCV.wait(loopLock);
          std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
          --threadCounter;
          if (threadCounter.load() == 0) {
            loopEndCV.notify_one();
          }
        }
        std::osyncstream oss{ std::cout };
        oss << "Ended thread " << i << std::endl;
      }
    );
  }


  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    threadCounter = numberOfThreads;
    myCV.notify_all();
    std::unique_lock loopEndLock(loopEndMutex);

    loopEndCV.wait(loopEndLock, [&threadCounter]() { return threadCounter.load() == 0; });
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
    std::cout << "Test loop " << i << std::endl;
  }

  isRunning = false;
  myCV.notify_all();

  return 0;
}
```

Basically I've added another `std::condition_variable`, that should notify when all threads end their loop iteration, so the main thread wait for this and it can go ahead when all iterations has ended. But this blocks completely the program (I print only the string before the creation of threads), so I've some deadlock somewhere or some other type of error, and I cannot solve this.

What I'm doing wrong? How can I fix the code

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like [`std::barrier`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/barrier).

Comment: Just because you have created 100 threads does not mean they have managed to run to the `myCV.wait(loopLock)` statement. Also, several threads can see `threadCounter` become zero and notify your loopEndCV at the same time.

Comment: As @G.M. wrote, go for `std::barrier`. The example on the referenced page is a great starting point to further elaborate on.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check `std::barrier`, it seems good for my case.